# Autohotkey key sequence not detected (win-alt-enter) '#' and '!' getting ignored

Tags: autohotkey, windows-media-center, syntax

I am trying to remap the MCE remote green button that sends <kbd>win</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>enter</kbd> (confirmed same LWin, LAlt, and Enter being sent) to just the windows key (LWin is fine). I found `#!Enter::` on several forums being noted as successful yet it isn't working for me.

This works:

```
j::LWin ;hit k and it emulated the windows key
```

These all do not work:

```
#!Enter::LWin

#!Enter::
    Send {LWin}
    return

#::w
!::i
```

These all do work:

```
LWin::w
LAlt::i
Enter::n
```

This won't run but presumably would work if it was correctly written:

```
LWin & LAlt & Enter::LWin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the keypress fires, the Lwin key is already down (as part of the combo), so it does nothing. Tell it to wait for the Lwin key to be released, then it will send it again by itself.

```
#!Enter::
Keywait Lwin
Send, {Lwin}
return
```

Comment: I swore I tested `#!Enter::w` but it turns out you were right. Is there a reason why `#::w` wasn't working? It may have just been an error on my part.